# Rijndael 256 encryption with Java & Bouncy Castle

Tags: java, encryption, rijndael

I'm working on a project built in pure php, i'm doing a rework on the login, but the users in the database are cipher in Rijndael-256, i've tried a lot of things and nothing seems to work, and i feel i'm so close with this code, but it doesn't work, and i'm really lost

```
private final String key = "...";

public String decrypt(String password, String cypherKey) {
    try {
        password = password.substring(0, password.lenght() - 1); // 1
        byte[] passwordBytes = password.getBytes("UTF-8");
        byte[] key = cypherKey.getBytes("UTF-8");

        RijndaelEngine rijndaelEngine = new RijndaelEngine(256);
        KeyParameter keyParam = new KeyParameter(key);
        rijndaelEngine.init(false, keyParam); // 2
        PaddedBufferedBlockCipher bufferedBlock = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(rijndaelEngine, new ZeroBytePadding());

        byte[] decryptedBytes = new byte[bufferedBlock.getOutputSize(passwordBytes.length)];
        int processed = bufferedBlock.processBytes(passwordBytes, 0, passwordBytes.length, decryptedBytes, 0);

        return String.valueOf(bufferedBlock.doFinal(decryptedBytes, processed));
    } catch (Exeption e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }

    return ""; // I know this is awful but i was trying something and left this like that
}
```

*1)  I don't know if this is right but all the encrypted passwords end with equals sign and i tested with an encryption tool and i don't think it's needed

2) False is decryption mode

**Stack trace**: org.bouncycastle.crypto.DataLengthException: last block incomplete in decryption

I'm working on this decryption for two weeks now, i'm really desperate :(

PHP code:

```
function fnEncrypt($sValue) 
{ 
    include("constants.php");

    return trim( 
        base64_encode( 
            mcrypt_encrypt( 

                MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,
                $SecretKey, $sValue,
                MCRYPT_MODE_ECB,


                mcrypt_create_iv( 
                    mcrypt_get_iv_size( 
                        MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,  
                        MCRYPT_MODE_ECB 
                    ),


                    MCRYPT_RAND) 
                ) 
            ) 
        ); 
} 

function fnDecrypt($sValue) 
{ 
    include("constants.php");

    return trim( 
        mcrypt_decrypt( 
            MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256,  
            $sSecretKey,  
            base64_decode($sValue),  
            MCRYPT_MODE_ECB, 

            mcrypt_create_iv(
                mcrypt_get_iv_size( 
                    MCRYPT_RIJNDAEL_256, 
                    MCRYPT_MODE_ECB 
                ),  
                MCRYPT_RAND 
            ) 
        ) 
    ); 
}
```

Comment: If possible, send the PHP-code for the encryption. For an implementation of the decryption, the details of the encryption must be known. Rijndael-256 (256 bits is the block size) is rather unusual (possibly confused with AES-256, where 256 bits is the key size). The equal sign indicates Base64-encoding.

Comment: I uploaded the php code, the method used it's deprecated in php so i think it's a big problem

Comment: FYI: ECB doesn't use IV, which is one of the things that makes it insecure for nearly all uses including this, but for modes that do use IV you must create a new one at (each) encrypt and store or transmit it and use the same one, NOT create a new one, at decrypt

Comment: I know that the method isn't secure, the system was made a couple years ago by some guy, we were hired to rebuild it, as i said in another comment, the old users have to access the page without any problem, so i had to cypher the password and match it with the one stored in DB

Answer (score 2):

In the `decrypt`-method, the ciphertext must first be Base64-decoded (1). In addition, the length of the decrypted text is not determined correctly (2a) and the length of the corresponding byte-array is not adjusted accordingly (2b). Finally, there is a problem in determining the UTF8-string from the byte-array (3). Modify the body of the `decrypt`-method as follows:

```
//password = password.substring(0, password.lenght() - 1); // 1                             // Remove
//byte[] passwordBytes = password.getBytes("UTF-8");                                        // Remove
byte[] passwordBytes = Base64.getDecoder().decode(password);                                // Base64-decode the ciphertext (1)
byte[] key = cypherKey.getBytes("UTF-8");

RijndaelEngine rijndaelEngine = new RijndaelEngine(256);
KeyParameter keyParam = new KeyParameter(key);
rijndaelEngine.init(false, keyParam); // 2
PaddedBufferedBlockCipher bufferedBlock = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(rijndaelEngine, new ZeroBytePadding());

byte[] decryptedBytes = new byte[bufferedBlock.getOutputSize(passwordBytes.length)];
int processed = bufferedBlock.processBytes(passwordBytes, 0, passwordBytes.length, decryptedBytes, 0);
processed += bufferedBlock.doFinal(decryptedBytes, processed);                              // Refresh the parameter containing the length of the decrypted data (2a)
decryptedBytes = Arrays.copyOfRange(decryptedBytes, 0, processed);                          // Reduce the byte-array accordingly (2b)

//return String.valueOf(bufferedBlock.doFinal(decryptedBytes, processed));                  // Remove           
return new String(decryptedBytes, "UTF-8");                                                 // Create a UTF-8 string from the byte-array (3)
```

with the imports `java.util.Base64` and `org.bouncycastle.util.Arrays`.

Even though this is probably legacy code, two notes on security: Passwords should generally not be encrypted, but [hashed](https://www.darkreading.com/safely-storing-user-passwords-hashing-vs-encrypting/a/d-id/1269374). In addition, [ECB](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/a/20946) is insecure.

Comment: Minor: copyOfRange not needed with `new String (decryptedBytes, 0, processed, charset)`

Comment: Thank you, i found the solution by using the same code i had, but in encryption mode, and modifying some things, i know the encryption isn't secure, but the system is really old, we were hired to rebuild the webpage, but it's important that te old users have access to their accounts

Answer (score 0):

This was my solution:

```
/**
     * Step 1: password and key are converted to bytes in order to be processed by the cypher.
     *
     * Step 2: a KeyParameter is created with the key bytes.
     *
     * Step 3: a PaddedBufferedBlockCipher statement is assigned with Rijndael 256 algorithm and ZeroBytePadding, this padder adds NULL byte padding to a block.
     *
     * Step 4: the bufferedBlockCipher is then initialized with parameters "true" meaning Encryption mode, and the KeyParameter.
     * This initialization prepares the bufferedBlock with the parameters needed for encryption.
     *
     * Step 5: a variable "buffer" stores the length in bytes the output should have
     *
     * Step 6: the processed bytes are calculated and stored, buffer now stores the value of the password
     *
     * Step 7: the encryption is finalized, the plus equals sign ensures that the output is multiple of 32
     *
     * Step 8: the buffer and processedBytes are converted into an array of bytes and then a String
     *
     * @param password
     *
     * @return
     */

    public String encrypt(String password) throws InvalidCipherTextException {
        byte[] data = password.getBytes();
        byte[] encryptionKey = key.getBytes();

        KeyParameter keyParameter = new KeyParameter(encryptionKey);

        PaddedBufferedBlockCipher bufferedBlockCipher = new PaddedBufferedBlockCipher(new RijndaelEngine(256), new ZeroBytePadding());
        bufferedBlockCipher.init(true, keyParameter);

        byte[] buffer = new byte[bufferedBlockCipher.getOutputSize(data.length)];
        int processedBytes = bufferedBlockCipher.processBytes(data, 0, data.length, buffer, 0);
        processedBytes += bufferedBlockCipher.doFinal(buffer, processedBytes);

        byte[] result = Arrays.copyOfRange(buffer, 0, processedBytes);
        String output = Base64.encodeBase64String(result);

        return output;
    }
```